# Using INSERT with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

there is a table customers with three columns (Id, name, Phone).
For example there is charachter with id 1 and name is Tom, and there are a lot of differents id and names so i need to add a phone number solely for tom in this sutiation, how can i do it?
i tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (Phone) values ('a Number') WHERE Id = 1;
```

I can get that i use condition "where" wrong, how should i use it right in my situation, please help, and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you actually want an *update* here:

```sql
UPDATE Customers
SET Phone = 'a Number'
WHERE Id = 1;
```

If you really do want to add a *new* record, then drop the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO Customers (Phone) VALUES ('a Number');
```

If the `Id` column be auto increment, then MySQL will auto generate a value for the `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

In the described case (update of already existing record) you should use UPDATE statement instead of INSERT:

```
UPDATE Customers SET Phone = "customer_phone_number_here" WHERE Id = 1;
```

Hope, [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) would be useful as well.